# Figure numbers overlapping text in LOF (list of figures)

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I'm getting overlap of the numbering of my figures in the LOF (list of figures) into the figure text like shown below.

[image]

I know there are other questions about this but this only happens to my figures list in the LOF and nothing else. I have however changed the figure numbering. I guess that's why this happens. Is there a way to change only the figure list of the LOF spacing between the numbers and the text?

EDIT: I'm using a LaTeX template provided by my university so there's a lot happening behind the curtains here. Even so I believe I should be able to change the numbering and spacing in the LOF without diving deep into the template setup. Code shown below. [GitHub thesis template](https://github.com/COPCSE-NTNU/bachelor-thesis-NTNU).

```
\documentclass[BIELE,norsk,oneside]{ntnuthesis/ntnubachelorthesis}
\usepackage{chngcntr}               
\counterwithin{figure}{section}    
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\begin{document}

\input{inc/BachelorThesisData} % this is the file which contains all the details about the thesis

\makefrontpages % make the frontpages

\input{inc/forord}


\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
%\lstlistoflistings


\input{inc/innledning}
\input{inc/teori}
\input{inc/metode}
\input{inc/resultater}
\input{inc/diskusjon}
\input{inc/konklusjon}


\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{inc/referanser}


\appendix %after this line all chapters will have letters instead of numbers

\end{document}
```

Comment: We could not help you much if you did not provide us with a minimal working example starting from `\documentclas` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Added updated description

Comment: This is not a self-contained sample because you are using files in your PC. To verify that the sample works on other PCs, create a new untitled document and copy the contents to that file and try to compile it.

Here is a quick solution: use `tocloft` package and fine-tune  

`\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{<value>}`
`\setlength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{<value>}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your given link and your given, not compiling code I created a compiling mwe using the document part of the given example bachelor thesis.

Then you can add package `tocloft` to change the width of the numbers displayed in your list of figures (LOF) with

```
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{1cm}
```

and for the list of tables (LOT) with

```
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{1cm}
```

Please change the used values `1cm` for your needs ...

With the following compiling mwe

```
\documentclass[BIELE,norsk,oneside]{ntnuthesis/ntnubachelorthesis}

\usepackage{tocloft} % <================================================
%\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{1cm} 
%\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{1.5cm} 
%\setlength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{2cm}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{1cm} % <====================================
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{1cm} 

\usepackage{chngcntr}               
\counterwithin{figure}{section}    
\counterwithin{table}{section}


\begin{document}

\input{inc/BachelorThesisData} % this is the file which contains all the details about the thesis

\makefrontpages % make the frontpages

\input{inc/preface}


\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings


\input{inc/introduction}
\input{inc/requirements}
\input{inc/technical}
\input{inc/process}
\input{inc/implementation}
\input{inc/deployment}
\input{inc/testing}
\input{inc/discussion}
\input{inc/conclusion}


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{inc/BachelorExample}

\appendix %after this line all chapters will have letters instead of numbers
\input{inc/projectplan}

%\input{inc/gantt}
\input{inc/meetinglog}
%\input{inc/worklog}

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting LOF and LOT]

As you can see and as also mentioned in the documentation of `tocloft` you need to add some `clearpage`s to get your TOC, LOF and LOT on separate pages as before ...  For me it was easier to show you both list of figures and tables without that `clearpage`s. So please change the given code above to

```
\input{inc/preface}

\clearpage % <=======================
\tableofcontents
\clearpage % <=======================
\listoffigures
\clearpage % <=======================
\listoftables
\clearpage % <=======================
\lstlistoflistings
```

Comment: This worked great. I appreciate it a lot.